# Tomcat 8 pause while serving the request

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm

Tomcat 8 pause for few minutes. Tomcat is not serving any request and response.
We have checked logs but not found any thing.

After some time it will automatically started working.

We have checked logs but not found any thing.
Checked thread dump but not found any thing.

We want to know the root cause of the issue and solution.

Comment: I don't think anybody can answer this with no details whatsoever.

Comment: Take a thread dump of the process while it's "paused". The thread dump will tell you exactly what is happening at that time. You say you checked it; what did it say? All threads waiting for new requests? When you say "pause", what _exactly_ do you mean? The response doesn't come back to the client? Hourglass cursor on the server? What kind of request? Simple GET? AJAX?